# EXCEL: Count Range; but Exclude blanks AND a specific string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel Version**: Microsoft 365 bundle (V 2106 Build: 14131.20278)

I'm trying to create an **Excel formula** that outputs a number onto a single cell (B11); the formula must:

- Count the number of cells that **HAVE DATA** on a given range [B2:B8];
- Therefore, IT must **NOT** count ***non-blank cells***; but must also **NOT INCLUDE** cells with a specific string (in this case the string would be "**N/A**") ;
- The formula must also count the number of ***line breaks*** [so Char(10)] present on that given range.

> I understand that it's not conventional to count inputted **line breaks** for a range; but that's what I need.

See the attached image:

[image: B11: Count from B2:B8 | No Blanks, no "N/A" string]

**RANGE** = In this example, the range of (non-blank AND non-"N/A") cells I want to count go from **B2** to **B8**.

**Cell w/ Formula**: B11

As of now, I only have the following formula done.

```
=SUM(LEN(B2:B8)-LEN(B2:B8;CHAR(10);""))+(LEN(B2:B8)>0))
```

> **This formula outputs** == "9" (i.e., 9 line breaks: ignores blanks, but includes the string "N/A")

This formula allows me to count all line breaks present on that given range (so, it doesn't count blank/empty cells), but it obviously **doesn't exclude** the specific string "N/A".

> **Expected output** == "8" (i.e., 8 line breaks: ignoring blank cells AND cells with the string "N/A")

I suppose this could be accomplished with an "IF", but I haven't figured it out yet.

Thank you for your time!

PS: I tried to make a table in here, but I was not able to add ***line breaks*** inside a single cell; so, I ended up resorting to an image to explain my point, sorry about the inconvenience!)

Comment: What version of Excel have you got ?

Comment: @JvdV ah yes; it's on Excel from the Microsoft 365 bundle (V 2106 Build: 14131.20278)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, since you have got access to Microsoft 365, try the following:

```
=SUM(FILTER(1+(LEN(B2:B8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B8,CHAR(10),""))),LEN(B2:B8)*(B2:B8<>"N/A"),0))
```

Nicely layed out question btw, and a fun little issue to work on. Hopefully the above helped you out.

Comment: this worked perfectly; also, thank you for your observation, I tried to make it as clear as I could.
Is there a better way to to ONLY SUM (well, "count", in this case) unique values?

The following formula gives me the solution that I want, but perhaps it could be shortened?

`=SUM(FILTER(1+(LEN(UNIQUE(B2:B8))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE(B2:B8),CHAR(10),""))),LEN(UNIQUE(B2:B8))*(UNIQUE(B2:B8)<>"N/A"),0))`

Comment: @heartborne, you are welcome. Consider to click the checkmark if it has answered your question. About your follow-up question: This could prove to be a bit more difficult since you may also be interested in possible dups after a newline-character instead of cells as a whole? This could prove to be a good follow-up question as a seperate post if you lay it out correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Just for a different approach:
(***edited after @ScottCraner pointed out it didn't account for N/A***)

```
=LET(x,FILTER($B$2:$B$8,B2:B8<>"N/A"),
     y,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,x),
     z,SUBSTITUTE(y,CHAR(10),""),
   LEN(y)-LEN(z)+1)
```

Of course, if you have a lot of data, `TEXTJOIN` will fail if the resultant string is > 32,767 characters

Comment: @ScottCraner It does now. Tks for pointing that out.

Comment: Very ingenious, although the char limitation could indeed be a problem. I lust learned LET because of you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do this with a simple `COUNTIF` (or `COUNTIFS` if you want to add more criteria to count against).

Try `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8, "<>N/A")`

EDIT1: As pointed out by cybernetic.nomad, a better approach to dealing with non-numeric data will be `COUNTA`. Another solution might be to just filter the whole data with something like:

`=COUNTA(FILTER($B$2:$B$8, $B$2:$B$8<>"N/A"))`

EDIT2: As pointed out by Scott Craner, this solution does not account for line breaks. You can add those in by using:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER($B$2:$B$8, $B$2:$B$8<>"N/A"))+
SUM(LEN($B$2:$B$8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$8,CHAR(10),"")))
```

Comment: It would also be worthwhile to look into [`COUNTA`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but wouldn't your EDIT2 solution still count blanks?
Perhaps one could fix it with:
`=COUNTA(FILTER($B$2:$B$8,($B$2:$B$8<>"N/A")*($B$2:$B$8<>""),0))+SUM(LEN($B$2:$B$8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$8,CHAR(10),"")))`

Comment: @Heartborne no problem, hope it helped. ```COUNTA``` only counts non-blanks